# Is there anyway way to speed up Exchange 2007's Load Generator tool?

Tags: exchange, exchange-2007, load-testing

I'm running Load Generator to test our new deployment before going live and the initialization process has been running for two days and is only at 25% for ~58000 user test.  Does anyone know of a way to speed up this process?  Surely it shouldn't take this long.

Currently, I've got it running with one master and two remote servers and they aren't peaking out on CPU or Network utilization.  Any help you could provide would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How about disk IO contention?

Comment: According to perfmon there is very little disk activity.

Comment: Nobody has any suggestions?